# How do I verify that two different objects attribute are different?

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I'm new to using the Yup validation schema method and I was wondering how I could compare two object to check that one of their respective attributes are different.

For example, I have the following code:

```
export default Yup.object().shape({
    personA: Yup.object().shape({
        id: Yup.number()
            .typeError("Must be a valid number")
            .required("Required field")
    }),
    personB: Yup.object().shape({
        id: Yup.number()
            .typeError("Must be a valid number")
            .required("Required field")
    })
});
```

In this case, how can I check that the objects personA and personB do not have the same id ?

Thank you for reading :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
yup.object().shape({
  object1: yup
    .object({
      attribute1: yup.string().required(),
      attribute2: yup.string().required(),
    })
    .required(),
  object2: yup
    .object({
      attribute1: yup.string().required(),
      attribute2: yup.string().required(),
    })
    .test('different', 'Attribute values must be different', function (value) {
      const object1 = this.parent.object1 || {};
      return value.attribute1 !== object1.attribute1 || value.attribute2 !== object1.attribute2;
    })
    .required(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#objectpickkeys-string-schema) method to pick the keys of those objects and compare, them like this-

```
const personA = object({
  id: Yup.number()
        .typeError("Must be a valid number")
        .required("Required field")
});

const idA = personA.pick(['id']);
```

```
const personB = object({
  id: Yup.number()
        .typeError("Must be a valid number")
        .required("Required field")
});
const idB = personB.pick(['id']);
```

```
idA.getDefault() // { id: <some_value> }
idB.getDefault() // { id: <some_value> }
```

Then you can compare those values.

Answer (score 0):

In your validation function, you can use the `this.parent` keyword to access the object that contains both `personA` and `personB`. A custom validation function can be used to make the comparison.

The `.compare()` method added to the `personB.id` validation schema in the code snippet below, accepts 3 arguemts, the first 2 are fairly self explanatory. The third argument is a validation function that takes in the value of `personB.id` and using the value of `personA.id` which is retrieved from the parent object using `this.parent` returns either true if the validation passes or a false if the validation fails.

If the validation fails (meaning the two IDs are the same), then the error message "IDs must be different, cowboy" will be displayed.

*Apologies for the horrible formatting also, using an outdated browser on an old testing phone to make this post.*

```
export default Yup.object().shape({
  personA: Yup.object().shape({
    id: Yup.number()
      .typeError("Must be a valid number")
      .required("Required field")
  }),
  personB: Yup.object().shape({
    id: Yup.number()
      .typeError("Must be a valid number")
      .required("Required field")
      .compare('not-same-id', 'IDs must be different cowboy', function(value) {
        const { personA } = this.parent; // get the value of personA from the parent object
        return value !== personA.id; // check if the value of id in personB is different from personA's id
      })
  })
});
```